# Usable code to stop a running code if "x" value is missing and do something and get back to the active cell and try to run the first code

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using `Excel VBA`.

What I want to do is run a code on Excel and if a value is missing that is needed to run this particular code the next step will be generated this value that is missing using another code and then get back to the first code and try to run it again.

Basically *if the value of the column F is missing then will go to other code and the run it and after get back to the first one and run it again.*

[image]

Comment: So what is your question? What did you try? Why didn't it work? What stops you from achieving your goal? Which errors did you get? [Without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/).

Comment: the code is really simple actually:

Comment: since i'm try to run a scrip on SAP MP1 the code is quite simple it's like

Comment: If (Cells(i, 10).Value <> "DAEN") And (Cells(i, 10).Value <> "ERROR") Then

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read up on acceptable posts: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. As you say, this is really simple. Just Google some beginner VBA tutorials

Comment: so i was think something like "on error go to" and then would run a new code because the value of the cell i,6 is missing and after run another code on this cell.. so i want to know how i get the code to run the first code on this same cell again after run the second code

Comment: basically the second one generated the missing information and then i need to run it again the first code on the same cell and only after this go to the next

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like the following:

The main code loops until cells in that row are valid. User gets the option to make cells valid or to abort. Your actual code only runs after validation got OK.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MainCode()
    Const i As Long = 2 'just for the example instead put your loop
    'For i = Start to Stop

        'loop until cells are valid or user canceled
        Do While AreCellsValid(Rows(i)) = False
            'this runs if cells are not valid
        
            Dim Cancel As Boolean
            CodeToMakeCellsValid Rows(i), Cancel
            If Cancel Then
                MsgBox "user aborted"
                Exit Sub
            End If
       Loop
    
        'here your code that should run if cells are valid
        MsgBox "all cells valid now run code"
    'Next i
End Sub

Private Function AreCellsValid(ByVal DataRow As Range) As Boolean
    AreCellsValid = True 'default is true
    
    If DataRow.Cells(1, "F").Value = vbNullString Then
        AreCellsValid = False
    ElseIf DataRow.Cells(1, 10).Value = "DAEN" Then 'just examples adjust your needs
        AreCellsValid = False
    ElseIf DataRow.Cells(1, 10).Value = "ERROR" Then
        AreCellsValid = False
    End If
End Function

Private Sub CodeToMakeCellsValid(ByVal DataRow As Range, Optional ByRef Cancel As Boolean = True)
    'put your code here to make cells valid
    'just an example
    
    Dim InputValue As Variant
    InputValue = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Input Functional Location:", Title:="Missign data", Type:=2)
    
    If VarType(InputValue) = vbBoolean And InputValue = False Then
        'user pressed cancel
        Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    Else
        DataRow.Cells(1, "F").Value = InputValue
    End If
End Sub
```